# Android HTTP-Post empty JSON

Tags: php, android, json, http-post

I need to send a json variable named "json" to the address
http://otu-git.dyndns.ws/pvm_srv/serv.php through android device
My current code is like this :

```
JSONObject jsn = new JSONObject();

JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

JSONObject header = new JSONObject();

try {

    header.put("txtUser", "123");
    header.put("md5Passwd", "123");
    header.put("fun", "validarUsuario");

    jsn.put("USR", header);

    json.put("json", jsn);
    se = new StringEntity(json.toString());     

} catch (Exception e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

try {

     params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json",json.toString()));
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
     Log.i("dhiraj",params.toString());
     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    entity = response.getEntity();
```

But I am getting Empty Json Post response from server !

Answer (score 0):

add headers like this

```
 httppost.addHeader("txtUser", "123");
        httppost.addHeader("md5Passwd", "123");
        httppost.addHeader("fun", "fun");
```

comment this line   `httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

else you can do like this

```
 ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtUser", "123"));   
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("md5Passwd", "123")); 
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fun", "fun"));

 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

Comment: I want to send the JSON object using HTTP_GET method. The php script will read from the given JSON object and validate the user and return Array
(
)
{"success":"true","nombre":"test"} But I am unable to get the expected response

Comment: have tried using above methods ?
yeah i have run a sample code using your url 
i am getting this response.
empty json POST
{"success":"false","m":"Estructura json malformada"}

Comment: I am asked to submit a JSON object named "json" to the site. It was specifically ased to submit JSON object named "json". the objects structure should be `{"USR":{"md5Passwd":"123","fun":"validarUsuario","txtUser":"123"}}` The response should be  `"{"success":"true","nombre":"test"}" `

Comment: use this

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json",jsn.toString()));

instead of   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json",json.toString()));
      
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));

Comment: comment this lines 
 json.put("json", jsn);
    se = new StringEntity(json.toString()); 
and use jsn .

Comment: Still I am not getting the success:true output !

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40724/discussion-between-dhiraj-tayade-and-user1920666)

Answer (score 0):

```
JSONObject jsn = new JSONObject();

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    JSONObject header = new JSONObject();

    try {

        header.put("txtUser", "123");
        header.put("md5Passwd", "123");
        header.put("fun", "fun");
        jsn.put("USR", header);

    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {

        if (SDK_INT >= 10) {
        ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
        }
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        // one of the method
        // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("txtUser", "123"));
        // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("md5Passwd", "123"));
        // params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fun", "fun"));

        // one of the method
        // // httppost.addHeader("txtUser", "123");
        // // httppost.addHeader("md5Passwd", "123");
        // // httppost.addHeader("fun", "fun");

        HttpPost httppost = null;
        httppost = new HttpPost("http://otu-git.dyndns.ws/pvm_srv/serv.php");

        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", jsn.toString()));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
        Log.i("dhiraj", params.toString());

        HttpClient httpclient = null;
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        String s = "";

    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();

    }
```

Comment: instead of writing in asynctask i used

        if (SDK_INT >= 10) {
        ThreadPolicy tp = ThreadPolicy.LAX;
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(tp);
        }